# Fingerprint has already been taken Gitlab

Tags: git

I deleted my local Gitlab repository (using Ubuntu) and recreated it. Now I wanted to add a new SSH key so I don't have to type email/pw on every push. What I did:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my@email.com"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then added the content of `id_rsa.pub` into the `key` form on Gitlab/SSH Keys. I deleted every old key in the settings and also every key in `~/.ssh/` before. And i still get the messages:

> Fingerprint has already been taken / Fingerprint cannot be generated